# Rules of replacement and implication to prove an argument.

Tags: logic

Solve this proof using the rules of replacement and implication:

1. (A∧H)→(M∧N)          P               / ∴ (A∧H)→N

This is my attempt so far

2. ¬(M∧N)→¬(A∧H)     1 trans
3. ¬(A∧H)∨(M∧N)        1 impl
4. ¬¬(M∧N)∨¬(A∧H)    2 impl
5. (M∧N)∨¬(A∧H)        4 DN

6.???

The rules I am trying to use are
Rules of implication: Modus Ponens, Modus Tollens, Hypothetical Syllogism, Disjunctive Syllogism, simplification, conjunction, addition, constructive dilemma

Rules of replacement: De Morgan's, distribution, double negation, commutation, association, implication, tautology, material equivalent, exportation.

Sorry I did not make my post concise. I am taking a symbolic logic course and have become stuck at looking at this proof. I am unsure what rules apply to reach the conclusion.

I will be better with posting on this forum in the future as this is my first time. Thank you so much for the guidance and help.

Comment: Have you made any attempt at all?  On this site we really expect you to do some work yourself. So, if you have made any attempts at all, please add that to your post. That way, we can give specific feedback so that *you* can *learn* something ... us just doing the problem for you teaches you nothing.

Comment: yes I have, I am stuck after trying to use these rules

Comment: Can you please add your attempt to your post, rather than in the Comments? Thanks!

Comment: You should also post the exact rules of the logic system you are working with .... and please don;t say 'the normal logic rules' because there are almost as many logic rule sets as there are logic textbooks

Comment: i think you forgot to mention the inference rule known as *conditional proof* as one of the rules you are able to use. It would be challenging to solve this without it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! OMG what a relief.

1. (A∧H)→(M∧N)          P               / ∴ (A∧H)→N
2. ¬(M∧N)→¬(A∧H)                    1 trans
3. ¬(A∧H)∨(M∧N)                        1 impl
4. (¬A∨¬H)∨(M∧N)                     3 DM
5. A→[(H→(M∧N)]                     1 exp
6. [¬(A∧H)∨M]∧[¬(A∧H)∨N]      3 dist

7.¬(A∧H)∨N                                6 simp

8. (A∧H)→N                                7 impl

VALID

Thank you for those trying to guide me with posting correctly on this forum.